# What is "Prerender requested by FlipAhead started for url: an unknown reason"?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have no idea about the `prerender` or `prefetch` as described in this [Prerender and prefetch support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265039(v=vs.85).aspx) article.

My site definitely has not implemented that feature. But when running in Edge browser, I got error:

> PRERENDER13101: Prerender requested by FlipAhead started for url: an unknown reason

[image]

How are we supposed to remove that error?

Comment: Which version of Edge are you seeing this in, and which site are you visiting? *prerender* and *prefetch* are methods of optimizing the user's experience upon navigating to predictable locations. If a user is on page 1 of 3, you can prerender/prefetch page 2 so that the document loads more quickly for the end-user should they decide to navigate there.

Comment: I have definitely no need to prefetch other resources. Even this `Prerender requested by FlipAhead` error also states "an unknown reason".

Comment: I'm happy to assist if you can provide repro steps, and URLs.

Comment: Why don't you try to disable FlipAhead? http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10350-internet-explorer-modern-flip-ahead-turn-off.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Browser configuration:

It is a browser configuration: Flip ahead allows you to explore favorite websites like you would a magazine

You can disable it like this:

```
Launch Internet Explorer 10. If you're using touch, swipe in from the right. If you're using a mouse, move the cursor to the top-right corner of the screen.
Tap or click Settings > Internet Options.
Under Flip ahead, toggle Turn on flip ahead to Off.
```

2. relation on your html page:

You can disable flip ahead in your html by removing the **rel**(relation) in href link:

```
<link rel="next" href="/news/article1.aspx?page=2"/>
```

**I think, there is somewhere in your html a relation(rel) that edge does not understand.**
That's why you have a prerender of prefetech of previous or next page error

3. Recognizing content patterns for paginated content

Flip ahead can recognize common content patterns in numerous languages to identify navigational elements in paginated content. These patterns range from simple text strings like "Next »" to complex elements incorporating numbers, symbols, and text strings.

For example, this element is a navigational element for paginated content on Bing:
1 2 3 4 5  next

**You may have a next(suivant, nächste, prossimo...) link in your page or a pattern matched by flip ahead. And so flip ahead will automatically recognize the next page, and trigger this prerender**

Note:
Be aware that you should not assume that having content patterns that match these examples will suffice to have flip ahead work on your website. If you want to ensure that flip ahead works reliably, always use rel="next".

From:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj883726(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just checked. No `rel` tag in my html. What else could trigger Prerender?